# How to migrate in Azure using ASP ABP?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How do we get migrations to work using ABP when using an Azure SQL server?

I tried
`myDbContext.Database.Migrate();` but myDbContext wants an options file.

I tried using `Update-Database` but it doesn't want to accept a ConnectionString.

I tried to enable migrations when publishing, but for some unknown reason, there is no "Migrate database on startup" option... very strange.

What's the right way to do this? SQL scripts?

Comment: remove "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" and then try

Comment: I ended up just generating SQL scripts and running them... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a connection string to Update-Database command.
Here's how to;

```
Update-Database -Verbose -ConnectionString "Server=localhost;Database=MyDatabase;User=sa;Password=123;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Here's a sample Azure db connection with Update-Database

```
Update-Database -StartUpProjectName "MyCloudProject" -ConnectionString "Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database_name>;User ID=<db_user_name>@<server_name>;Password=<password>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=100;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Can't do it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: this is a big handicap but nope